# SSL decryption without installing a certificate on each client

Tags: encryption, tls, certificates, man-in-the-middle, proxy

Given a proxy performing MITM SSL decryption and inspection, is it possible to install a wildcard certificate (*.domain.com) on the proxy signed by a root CA (such as VeriSign or GoDaddy) such that clients will not have to have a self-signed cert installed (since they will already trust the root CAs in their trusted store)?

I'm thinking about this in terms of allowing BYOD devices on a network and avoiding the necessity of installing a cert on different device types such as iOS, Android, Windows Phone, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible with certain configurations of proxy servers. Usually SSL proxies are put in place to proxy *all* outbound traffic, not just traffic to a server that you own, which is why you typically need to install the SSL proxy cert on all devices. If you want to only proxy traffic to *one* domain for which you have a cert signed by a root authority, then you should be able to install that wildcard cert on the proxy and not need anything from the clients.

Comment: Kevin, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!